# Magento admin panel is completely blank. Nicht gut

Tags: magento

Morning,

So we've got a Magento installation that's been working fine for two months, processing orders, managing inventory and being amazing as a good website should.

The problem is, today the Magento admin panel has completely stopped working. Nightmare. You can browse to /admin and see the login panel, but once you've logged in the admin panel stares back in a pool of white.

This is the URL it gets to and fails on:

http://www.[domainname].com/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/2448826287818da25840ae673d1198f6/

There's literally NO html being created. The HTACCESS hasn't been changed, and there aren't any errors being generated in /var. I've tried removing the caches to no avail. What would you do to solve this awful situation?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I'd say the first port of call are the Magento Error logs in `(magento root)/var/log`

Comment: Ah, I just saw on second read that you already looked there. Sorry

Comment: Thanks anyway Pekka. You helped me find out what was up though mate — enabled error reporting in Magento and found out that the server is out of memory.

The person that runs the server must have shafted the client! Nasty.

Comment: ah, nice! I'm adding an answer of my own, though: It's not necessarily a malicious act.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Out of Memory` error message is not the *server* hitting a memory limit; It is the script-instance-specific `memory_limit` setting in PHP.

Meaning, it's not necessarily a malicious act on the admin's end.

What you need to do is to change PHP's `memory_limit` setting to a higher value, like 32 MB. How Magento ever managed to run with 13 Megabytes is a mystery to me. It could be that this value has been changed recently, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 4):

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 13369344) (tried to allocate 1572864 bytes) in [clientroot]\htdocs\product\lib\Zend\Date.php on line 2379

Can't allocate 1.5MB? The person running our client's "dedicated server" is shafting them. Time to bring out the beasts...

For anyone with unknown problems in magento, add this in index.php below the error reporting settings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Preserve (log) your site’s PHP errors via **.htaccess**

```
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```